# How to create listview in android with mixed of checkbox and edittext along with textview?

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, dynamic-list

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>S.NO</th>
    <th>Description</th> 
    <th>Observation</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Check the U/S Wheel assembly and the accompanying documents are available.</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Check the tyre pressure as received condition _________________ Psi.</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Carryout leak test on Over inflation Valve <input type="checkbox"> & Thermal fuse<input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

How to create this kind of table in android with run-time value? 
I want to create listview with mix of checkbox and edittext to fill the survey form.
 
example shown in snippet, kindly look over it. Kindly help me get out from this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _sigh_ What have you tried so far? Have you created the listview yet? If there're only 3 rows then you probably don't need a listview. Check out how to create [Table](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html)s in android

Comment: its an sample data, the list contain more than 100 row

Comment: Then check out how to create [listviews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) or [recyclerviews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html)

Comment: how can i create list with combination of checkbox and edittext if required

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android listview with editText and checkbox for each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542708/android-listview-with-edittext-and-checkbox-for-each-element)